# "@metamask/detect-provider: Unable to detect window.ethereum" error even though Metamask is installed and running

Tags: javascript, smartcontracts, metamask

I am trying to run a basic program that detects if the user has window.ethereum installed. When I run my program I get "@metamask/detect-provider: Unable to detect window.ethereum", even though I have Metamask installed and running in my browser. Has anyone had similar problems? Thanks in advance.

Javascript:

```
import detectEthereumProvider from '@metamask/detect-provider';
 
const provider = await detectEthereumProvider();
 
if (provider) {
 
  console.log('Ethereum successfully detected!');
 
  })
} else {
 
  console.error('Please install MetaMask!', error);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Turns out this was rather simple. Metamask only injects window.ethereum into visited websites that are running on an http server. I just had to open my website using a localhost server from Node.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if metamask is installed, you can do it this way:

```
if (window.ethereum && window.ethereum.isMetaMask) {
  // metamask is installed
}
```

Metamask is adding `window.ethereum` object to the browser. The code above is checking if there's `window.ethereum` object available in client browser and second condition, `window.ethereum.isMetaMask` is checking if the `window.ethereum` object is injected by metamask.

Comment: Providers can be either synchronously or asynchronously injected:

Synchronously injected providers will be available by the time website code starts executing.
Asynchronously injected providers may not become available until later in the page lifecycle.

The MetaMask extension provider is synchronously injected, while the MetaMask mobile provider is asynchronously injected.

Comment: old clients still inject web3. it is still good practising to detect web3